# PHP regular expression - get text between slashes

Tags: regex

I need the following but I don't know how to do this .. with Regular Expression.

First problem

> From $uri = '/page/subpage/?vars=bla' I want to extract only
>   '/page/subpage/';

Second problem

> The $uri = '/page/subpage/?vars=bla' I want to convert it to a
>   friendly version '/page/subpage/vars-bla/'; Right now I can make it
>   '/page-subpage-vars-bla/' but I want to keep the slashes.

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 2):

**First problem solution:**

```
preg_match("/(.*)\\/([^\\/]+)/", '/page/subpage/?vars=bla', $split);
echo $split[1] . "/";
```

Output:

```
/page/subpage/
```

**Second problem:**

```
preg_match("/(.*)\\/([^\\/]+)/", '/page/subpage/?#$Q@DFSDFvars=bla', $split);
echo $split[1] . "/" . str_replace("=", "-", $split[2]) . "/";
```

Output:

```
/page/subpage/?#$Q@DFSDFvars-bla/
```

Comment: Regarding the first problem .. I need regex because it can be /page/subpage/#bla, /page/subpage/@bla etc - All kind of chars ~`!@#$%^ &*()_+=. And is not working. Thanks however!

Comment: Also the same problem for my second problem .. It can be '/page/subpage/!@#$vars=bla'

Comment: Updated first solution, thinking about the second one.

Comment: Ok got it, both of the regular expressions are now the same, so you can use 1 regular expression for both problems. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)?

```
$uri = '/page/subpage/?vars=bla';
parse_url($uri);
```

Results...

```
array
  'path' => string '/page/subpage/' (length=14)
  'query' => string 'vars=bla' (length=8)
```

Comment: The function "is intended specifically for the purpose of parsing URLs and not URIs", but it works. And to be sure you can always add a fake scheme+host: `$url = 'http://fake.org' . $uri;`

Comment: True: this solution only works with URIs compliant with [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986).